# funçao de saida dando erro sintaxe

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
lista1 = [1,2,3,1,1]
lista2 = [2,2,3,1,3]
res = list(input("Digite seus inteiros"))
def exibiçao(lista1,lista2,res):

print("{} {} {} {} {}".format(lista1[4],lista1[3],lista1[2],lista1[1],lista1[0] ))
print("{} {} {} {} {}".format(lista2[4],lista2[3],lista2[2],lista2[1],lista2[0] ))
print("--------------------------")
print("{} {} {} {} {}".format(res[4],res[3],res[2],res[1],res[0] ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Evite palavras latinas, como exibição, caso deseja manter o nome coloque exibicao sem a acentuação, lembre que a língua inglesa não possui tais sinais gráficos.

Além disso, você esqueceu de fechar os parentes, por consequência desse ato ocorreu os erros.

Espero ter ajudado.

```js
lista1 = [1, 2, 3, 1, 1]
lista2 = [2, 2, 3, 1, 3]
res = [3, 4, 6, 2, 4]


def exibicao(lista):

  return len(lista)


print("{}, {}, {}, {}, {} ".format(lista1[4], lista1[3], lista1[2], lista1[1], lista1[0]))

print("{}, {}, {}, {}, {}".format(lista2[4], lista2[3], lista2[2], lista2[1], lista2[0]))

print("Tamanho da lista igual a ", exibicao(lista2))

print("{}, {}, {}, {}, {}".format(res[4], res[3], res[2], res[1], res[0]))
```

Comment: se meu res fosse entrado pelo usuario como resolver ?

Comment: basta passar a lista rest como parâmetro. Por exemplo: exibicao(rest). Ou seja, pode informar qualquer parâmetro, seguindo o mesmo tipo da variável.

Comment: exatamente q o alexandre disse

Comment: Não vejo por que não usar acentos na função - o python aceita isso normalmente, então esse tipo de recomendação não faz sentido nessa linguagem.